# Opening docx or pptx files in Office Web Apps 2013 results in the error "Sorry, Word Web App ran into a problem opening this document

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, owa

The problem I am facing matches exactly with the problem I have found [here](http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2014/01/office-web-app-ran-into-problem-opening.html#comment-form). They provide solution also but I am not able to understand it. Can someone please explain it in detail?

Following is the problem I've copied from the site.

**Problem:** Opening docx or pptx files in Office Web Apps 2013 results in the error "Sorry, Word Web App ran into a problem opening this document. To view this document please open it in Microsoft Word."

[image]

**Resolution:**  I don't like it but I had to remove the link to the WCA farm, rebuild the WCA farm and hoop SP2013 back to the WCA farm.  [sic].  Other documents were opening and I realised that my bindings were incorrect after I rebuilt.